# Material-UI Datagrid - issue editing cells when displaying a string in place of NaN

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm playing around with the material-ui datagrid component, but I'm running into a minor issue when attempting to edit a cell that potentially displays a string while the underlying format is a number. Some of my data has a value of NaN, which I don't want to display, I'd rather show a string like 'N/A', so I'm using a `valueGetter` to handle this logic, though I'm starting to think this is incorrect. I have also defined a `valueSetter` to set user entered values in the nested data object.

Editing in the datagrid works just fine, but every time I edit a cell that has a display value of N/A, I see a warning message logged to the console:

```
The specified value "N/A" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.
```

I think I understand why this is happening, the 'N/A' string is being passed to an input element with type='number' and the N/A obviously can't be parsed into a number.

I haven't been able to find away around this issue yet. I imagine there is something in the API that would allow me to 'convert' the N/A back to NaN (or zero) before the value gets passed to the input element, but I haven't come across it yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Demo available at: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-voice-bx8n7x?file=/demo.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid, GridColumns, GridRowsProp } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const columns: GridColumns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "Id", width: 180 },
  {
    field: "data",
    headerName: "Value",
    type: "number",
    editable: true,
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      const val = params?.value?.value;
      return val && !Number.isNaN(val) ? val : "N/A";
    },
    valueSetter: (params) => {
      const newValue = Number(params.value);
      params.row["data"].value = newValue;
      return { ...params.row };
    }
  }
];

const rows: GridRowsProp = [
  {
    id: 1,
    data: {
      name: "cat",
      value: 2
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: {
      name: "dog",
      value: NaN
    }
  }
];

export default function BasicEditingGrid() {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 300, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```